# SQL Server : SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)

Tags: sql-server

Am seeing this in a script

```
SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
```

I know what it does. It is returning a column called 'n' with 4 rows, each of whose value is 0.
But, what does this mean? What is t(n), and what is 'n'?

Comment: 't' is the table alias, 'n' is the alias of the first column

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx). t being the alias for the table, n the column name. A better example might make it clearer;

```
SELECT 
    MyData.Column1, 
    MyData.Column2 
FROM (VALUES(1, 'Tom'),
            (2, 'Dick'),
            (3, 'Harry'),
            (4, 'Ermintrude')
      ) MyData(Column1, Column2)
```

returns

```
Column1     Column2
----------- ----------
1           Tom
2           Dick
3           Harry
4           Ermintrude
```

Answer (score 6):

`t` is the table alias. While `n` is the name to give to the column

`SELECT * FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) TheAlias(theColumn)`

Gives:

```
theColumn
0
0
0
0
```